# How to retrieve webservice response from WebView in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-webview

I had a scenario where I have a URL for which I make a http get request  using HttpClient. The URL opens up webpage in Webview with some form. On Click of Button in that form it generates some JSON response.  How to obtain JSON response from WEBView to the calling activity in Android.

How can I sort out this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling network call from WebViewClient, use one interface and do all networking operations in AsyncTask. Second thing pageFinish get called more than once, so no need of flag but get url and then validate if it is correct or not in the callback method.

To pass data from customWebClient to activity, create one interface and implement it in your activity, and using it pass your url from shouldOverrideurlLoading to the activity.

```
public interface ICallback{
    public void passData(String url);
}

public class myActivity extends Activity implements iCallback{
    public void passData(String url){
        //validate url
        //call async task to get result
    }
}

public CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient{

   iCallback mCallback;

   public CustomWebViewClient(Context context, ICallback callback){
      mCallback = callback;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, String url) {
       mCallback.passData(url);
       return true;
   }
   return false
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should override the shouldOverrideUrlLoading method of WebViewClient

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, String url) {

    if(flag) { 

            URL aURL = new URL(url); 
            URLConnection conn = aURL.openConnection(); 
            conn.connect(); 
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream(); 
            // read inputstream to get the json..
            ...
            ...
            return true;
    }

    return false
}

@override
public void onPageFinished (WebView view, String url) {
    if (url contains "form.html") {
        flag = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: where should  I declare  the variable flag ?

Comment: Can I declare the variable with default value as "false" ?

Comment: Thank you. I will  try with the info provided by you.